# Getting a JavaExecutionException on my invoke method?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to invoke a method by means of reflection. The signature of the method I'm trying to get is as follows:

```
public static JPAQuery find(String query, Object... params) {...}
```

I used the following snippet to get the declared method:

```
Method findEntities = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("find", params);
```

I'm trying to invoke with the following snippet:

```
Object[] args = new Object[2];
args[0] = fieldName + " = ?"; // Of type String
args[1] = entity; // Of a type extending GenericModel
JPAQuery query = (JPAQuery)findEntities.invoke(null, args); <-- EXCEPTION HERE!!!
```

...but getting the following exceptions:

```
play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: argument type mismatch
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

and

```
play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: wrong number of arguments
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

Can anyone help with this?

**Further Observation**

When I change the line:

```
JPAQuery query = (JPAQuery)findEntities.invoke(null, args);
```

to

```
JPAQuery query = (JPAQuery)findEntities.invoke(null, fieldName, entity);
```

one of the exception stating "wrong number of arguments" disappear. So I only have the argument type mismatch issue now. Almost there... :D

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? `Class#getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)` is the correct signature - you appear to be passing in an array of Objects as `params`.

Comment: @Bringer128, the call to getDeclaredMethod is working 100%. When I debug and inspect the findEntities var, it's clear that the method was successfully retrieved. My problem is the line I marked EXCEPTION HERE, the point where I'm passing args, as the 2nd argument is wrong, and I'm not entirely sure what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public static JPAQuery find(String query, Object... params)

That vararg parameter is just a pretty syntax for `Object[] params`.

So you need to pass in two parameters, the String, and an Object array with your entity.

```
JPAQuery query = (JPAQuery)findEntities.invoke(
     null, fieldName, new Object[]{ entity} );
```

Comment: Fixed, thanks for that! I was just about to post my own answer then your answer came through. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
findEntities.invoke(null, args);
```

Here the first parameter should be the object the method is invoked from. You pass null, so it can´t work.

For further information see the documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Additionally I would chance the line:

```
Method findEntities = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("find", params);
```

To

```
Object[] params = new Object[1];
params[0] = Object.class;
Method findEntities = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("find", params);
```

Comment: I understand that the first parameter has to be null, as the method being executed is static.

Comment: Hmm yes the documentation says it is ignored and may be null.